# Run-time error 459 when using WithEvents with a class that implements another

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am developing a VBA project in Word and have encountered a problem with handling events when using a class that implements another.

I define an empty class, `IMyInterface`:

```
Public Sub Xyz()
End Sub

Public Event SomeEvent()
```

And a class, `MyClass` that implements the above:

```
Implements IMyInterface

Public Event SomeEvent()

Public Sub Xyz()
  ' ... code ...
  RaiseEvent SomeEvent
End Sub

Private Sub IMyInterface_Xyz()
   Xyz
End  Sub
```

If I create a third class, `OtherClass`, that declares a member variable with the type of the interface class:

```
Private WithEvents mMy As IMyInterface
```

and try to initialize this variable with an instance of the implementing class:

```
Set mMy = New MyClass
```

I get a run-time error '459': This component doesn't support this set of events.

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264500%28VS.60%29.aspx) for this error message states:

> "You tried to use a WithEvents
>   variable with a component that can't
>   work as an event source for the
>   specified set of events. For example,
>   you may be sinking events of an
>   object, then create another object
>   that Implements the first object.
>   Although you might think you could
>   sink the events from the implemented
>   object, that isn't automatically the
>   case. Implements only implements an
>   interface for methods and properties."

The above pretty much sums up what I'm trying to do. The wording, "that isn't automatically the case", rather than "this is flat-out impossible", seems to suggest that there is some bit of manual work I need to do to get it to work, but it doesn't tell me **what**! Does anybody know if this is possible in VBA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently Events are not allowed to be passed through an interface class into the concrete class like you want to using "Implements".  In this article it states: "Event declarations of the abstract interface are not included in the interface that is inherited by concrete classes. I haven't found anywhere that this has been acknowledged as a bug; however, it does seem to be one."

Here is the link to the source: http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20416

:-(

Comment: Thanks for that; looks like it's a bug all right. I wish the MSDN hadn't gotten my hopes up! Still, I think I have a workaround, though using events would have been more elegant. C'est la vie.

Comment: @KenKeenan not a bug, rather how COM events work. You can use events together with interfaces using an adapter pattern, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45825831/1188513). (sorry to wake the dead with this comment - this Q&A was linked from a recent question... and the topic is fascinating IMO)