# MS Access Copying a Button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a series of forms and on each one I would like to add a Back button, so I created a command button and to the on click event assigned it trigger the following VBA;

```
Private Sub cmdBack_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_CmdBack_Click

    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    DoCmd.Close

Exit_CmdBack_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_CmdBack_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_CmdBack_Click

End Sub
```

How can I now, or what is the best way, to copy this button to all the other forms with the code? If I just copy and paste I lose the code and I don't want to re-write the code for each button that seems inefficient.

Comment: But that's what you have to do: _copy button, copy code._

Comment: @Gustav But what about an embedded macro? I've used that before but I don't know how to change the VBA to one of those. Then it's wrote once assign many?

Comment: You wouldn't want that. Using those, turns debugging into a potential nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to go about code reusability in forms in Access.

For this example, you could simply use a function in a separate module, and bind the button to that:

```
Public Function formBack()
On Error GoTo Err_CmdBack_Click

    If Screen.ActiveForm.Dirty Then Screen.ActiveForm.Dirty = False
    DoCmd.Close

Exit_CmdBack_Click:
    Exit Function

Err_CmdBack_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_CmdBack_Click
End Function
```

(If you press a button on a form, it's always the active form).

You can bind the button to this function by setting it's `On Click` property to `=formBack()`

There are alternate ways to reuse code. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023670/can-we-use-interfaces-and-events-together-at-the-same-time) has some nice answers, demonstrating some of the more complex ones.