# Implementing interface's event in VBA

Tags: vba, interface, mvp

I have an interface IView:

```
 Option Explicit

Public Event OnClientSelected()

Public Property Get ClientNames() As Variant
End Property
(...)
```

But I am not able to implement the event in my user form. Properties and subs are allowed to implement, but event not.

Is it possible to make interface implementation with events?

Comment: Did you declare the IView object in the form WithEvents?

Comment: I want the form to be an implementation of the interface, so I don't have IView object. I use: Implements IView

Comment: An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice. I don't think you can directly have event handling and inteface (WithEvents and Implements). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023670/can-we-use-interfaces-and-events-together-at-the-same-time

Comment: No, it isn't possible. The best way to verify this is by not implementing the `Event` along with the rest of the interface.  This still compiles - if the `Event` was considered part of the interface you'd get a compile error.

Answer (score -1):

Did you use withevents?

I've done the following, added a `test` function to your class

```
Private WithEvents iface As clsIface

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set iface = New clsIface
End Sub

Private Sub iface_OnClientSelected()
    '   Event subscription
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    iface.test
End Sub
```

Function added to class

```
Public Function test()
    RaiseEvent OnClientSelected
End Function
```